# Can one sell a future contract?

Tags: halacha, business, contemporary-halacha

In the modern marketplace, to protect against volatility and risk, people negotiate contracts that deal with things that are yet to become a reality.

However, as I read the gemara in Bava Metzia [33b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.33b.13?lang=bi&with=Talmud&lang2=en), along with Mishneh Torah: Sales [22:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sales.22?lang=en) and Shulchan Aruch Choshen Mishpat [209:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.209.4?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en), this practice seems forbidden.

My question is this: what are the modern halachic opinions about the possible permissability of trading in such future (and therefore non-existent) goods and how do they interpret the sources above?

Comment: I didn't check all your sources but suspect they all might refer to the impossibility rather than the prohibition of such trade. In any event, if you do see prohibition, why are you asking if there's prohibition? Are those sources insufficient?

Comment: To repeat msh210: "לֹא קָנָה כְּלוּם" means the contract/the sell is invalid, it does not forbid such contracts.

Comment: @msh210 I am asking for more modern sources/application of those sources to the modern marketplace, where I assume futures are sold much more commonly than when the sources I found were written